# Java API Deprecations

Tags: java, java-ee

Who decides the API deprecations the JEE specification or the vendor of JDK like Sun, IBM?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Spec Lead and the EG group will decide via a JSR as part of the [Java Community Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Community_Process).  They are typically conservative in their deprecation and remove cycles.